# Как в методе класса объявить параметр метода с типом этого же класса?

Tags: python, классы, ссылки

Пример:

```
class PackageInfo:
    def depends_on(self, package: PackageInfo):
        result = self.required_package_list.index(package.package_name) > -1
        return result
```

Python ругается на объявление - `package: PackageInfo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Имя в кавычки возьмите.

```
def depends_on(self, package: 'PackageInfo')
```

Прочитать об этом можно тут: [forward-reference](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references).

Comment: Спасибо. Помогли новичку

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
class PackageInfo:
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.package_name = '1'
        self.required_package_list = ['1', '2', '3']

#    def depends_on(self, package: PackageInfo):
    def depends_on(self):
#        result = self.required_package_list.index(self.package_name) > -1
        result = self.package_name in self.required_package_list
        return result
        
packageInfo = PackageInfo()
result = packageInfo.depends_on()
print(f'\nresult    = {result}')  

packageInfo.package_name = '22'
result = packageInfo.depends_on()
print(f'\nresult 22 = {result}') 

packageInfo.package_name = '2'
result = packageInfo.depends_on()
print(f'\nresult  2 = {result}')
```

Comment: Мой выбор forward-reference, но все равно спасибо

Comment: @Сергей пожалуйста. Но мне кажется, что вы к этому еще вернетесь. И не забудьте отметить ответ, который решил вашу проблему, как правильный. Если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Вы не точно ответили на мой вопрос.

Comment: Вы не точно ответили на мой вопрос. В моей реализации метод depends_on проверяет есть ли ссылка на объект package в required_package_list. А Ваш код предлагает проверять наличие self в этом списке. В любом случае примите мою благодарность за попытку оказать помощь